# Calling a procedure during assert in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-assert

I have an assert query that is something like:

```
:- dynamic a/1,b/1.

dump:- listing(a),listing(b).

main:-retractall(a(X)),assert(a(1):-write('aa')),
      retractall(b(X)),assert(b(1):-write('bb')).
```

I want the user to type `a(1)` or `b(1)`, the program to display `aa` or `bb` respectively (so far so good) and then to call another procedure,depending on what the user has typed.

For instance, if he typed `a(1)`, I want a procedure called `pro_a` to run, and respectively if he types `b(1)`, a procedure `pro_b` will run

These procedures will be:

```
  pro_a:- retractall(a(X)),retractall(b(X)),write('you chose a'),
          assert(a(1):-write('aa1')).

  pro_b:- retractall(a(X)),retractall(b(X)),write('you chose b'),
          assert(b(1):-write('bb1')).
```

and so on.

What I tried is something like:

```
assert(a(1):-write('aa'),pro_a).
```

But that doesn't work.
Is `assert` supposed to have only one command? (I'm not sure how to explain this).

Comment: You need an extra set of parentheses: `assert((a(1):-write('aa'),pro_a)).`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Do I need to add an extra set of parentheses for every procedure?

Comment: No, the assert needs it because of the operator precedence of `:-`. If you were asserting a simple fact, for example, it would just be `assert(foo(1)).`.

Comment: Yeah,but if i wanted to run pro_a and pro_b, would it be like 
`assert(((a(1):-write('aa'),pro_a),pro_b)).` ?

Comment: That would be an error since the form of what you wrote is `assert((..., ...)).` so it is attempting to redefine `,`.